# Error sending JSON object as a POST request [VB.NET]

Tags: json, vb.net, post

I am trying to send JSON object from VB.NET app (3.5 Framework).

I am using this code:

```
 Private Function sendSMS()
        Dim objHTTP As Object
        Dim json As String
        Dim result As String
        Dim URL As String

        json = fJSON()
        objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        URL = "https://api.XXXXXXXXX.com/api/3.0/sms/send"
        objHTTP.Open("POST", URL, False)
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        objHTTP.send(json)
        result = objHTTP.responseText
        objHTTP = Nothing    
    End Function

    Private Function fJSON() As String
        fJSON = "{"
        fJSON = fJSON & """api_key"":""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"","
        fJSON = fJSON & """concat"":1,"
        fJSON = fJSON & """fake"":1,"
        fJSON = fJSON & """messages"":["
        fJSON = fJSON & "{"
        fJSON = fJSON & """from"":""SHOP"","
        fJSON = fJSON & """to"":""3400000000"","
        fJSON = fJSON & """text"":""LOREM IPSUM"""
        fJSON = fJSON & "}]}"
    End Function
```

But I am getting this error in the line code:

Line code:

```
objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
```

Error:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error no especificado**

What is wrong?

Comment: im not a vb.net expert but shouldnt your fJSON() function return a value?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yes, it returns a string.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes user doesn't have enough privileges to run some COM Methods. Here your exception says "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005)" which is based on System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. To sort it out, Will you ran Visual Studio as Administrator and check wheather that logic works for you or not?

Comment: Now I have tried running as Administrator but I get the same error.